# New-Item creates file instead of directory about 10% of the time

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script I've been having problems with for several months. The script counts the number of pages in a folder of tif files, and then then breaks up the folder into subfolders of around 50 pages each. In my test environment (Setup the same as production) It ran through a test base of over 1000 tif files without a single error. 
After we promoted it to the production environment we've started experiencing script crashes where the following code will create a file without an extension instead of creating a folder, and then will no longer be able to process files.

```
    if(!(Test-Path $processingDir))
      {
         New-Item $processingDir -ItemType directory
         $FolderCount = $FolderCount + 1
      }
```

There are several other places where I use the New-Item <> -ItemType Directory command, and those work around 99% of the time, but occasionally they will create a file instead of a folder as well.

This script runs every five minutes on a schedule, so about 4-5 times a day we have to go out and delete the file it creates before the script will be able to complete successfully again.

I've also had a ton of issues with brackets in file names, and issues powershell errors thrown when there's error output from the script, but my understand is that there's no known fix for that. I'd ideally like to reprogram this script in another less finicky language but there's no time bandwidth.

I have Powershell 2.0 installed on all of my systems.

Comment: How is $processingDir being defined?

Comment: $processingDir = "$destination\processing1\" 
$Destination is a parameter passed into the script by Tidal (Scheduling program)

Comment: Can you provide contents of `$destination` from a working and a non-working run? Are there ever any non-alphanumeric characters in it?

Comment: Graham: The Destination should never change, as it's hard coded into the scheduling system. It changes based on the client, but we see the erratic errors on all clients with this script. The Destination variable will look like this: //<servername>/<Env>/clientprocessing/<client>/<solutionset>/

Comment: That's what I was getting at - what kind of data are you passing to $processingDir? It sounds like some of the names you're trying to use are confusing PowerShell. New-Item doesn't randomly ignore the -ItemType parameter, so if you're running it repeatedly with different values for -Path and it occasionally fails to act as expected, the problem would have to lie in what those values are when it fails. What does the output from Tidal look like?

Comment: Are the directories always local or are they over a network share? What about the drives themselves: are they connected locally over the motherboard sata bus, via USB, on a NAS or a SAN?

Comment: The only time the name of the folders being created change are in the other areas of the code, the processing1 folder is the initial copy location for the script, and is the same for every run.

Comment: I would have guessed that *something else* creates the file, and then powershell (obviously) fails to create the folder with the same name as OS won't allow it. If you provide the output of the powershell script it could help. The main thing is not to see just the final error but whatever is happening *before* it. It is also possible, that your conclusion, that this piece of code is culprit is incorrect, and problem lies elsewhere. Tell us more.

Comment: I'm not getting any sort of error output from the code when this happens aside from errors related to the script trying to movie files into a folder that doesn't exist. I get an error that a file already exists every once and a while, but I didn't think it was related. I added a bit of code yesterday to check to see if the processing1 file exists, and if it does delete it and create the folder, so I'll see how that goes. More of a bandaid than a fix though.

Comment: Also, the directories are always network locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of systematic troubleshooting and bug searching I found out what was causing the issue by shear dumb luck. I happened to be looking at the right file at just the right time and saw what happened. 
There's another script that operates on the directory we were moving files to, that them fed the files we were copying out into another software product to be processed. What was happening was that the second script was removing the folder while Powershell was moving the files into it, which for some reason made Powershell create the junk file (Leaf).
Solved this by having my stuff get processed into another file, and then bulk moved over into the second folder.

Thanks for the answers everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following. Hopefully putting quotes around $processDir will fix the error, but the debug info might help if it doesn't.

```
if(!(Test-Path "$processingDir"))
  {
     New-Item "$processingDir" -ItemType directory
     if (!(Test-path "$processingDir") -or !(ls "$processingDir").PSIsContainer) {
       # Something went wrong. These error messages will go to the console screen,
       # but you could write them to a log file if you have one
       write-host ("!"*35) "  ERROR  " ("!"*35)
       write-host "ProcessingDir = '$processDir' (check for special chars in dir name)"
       write-host "Displaying ""DIR $processingDir"" (is there a file with this name?)"
       ls "$processDir"
       write-host ("!"*35) " END ERROR " ("!"*35)
     }
     $FolderCount = $FolderCount + 1
  }
```

Comment: Through some other research I found the flag -PathType Leaf so I put in a simpler test based on that, I think it worked well. I'll be moving it into production this afternoon so I'll update to see if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my understanding is right: the script is running on clients. Clients run the script and do all the file/folder processing on the server (since I saw you just mentioned "server name"). So although you have several (or lots of) clients running this script but the location of file/folder processing is still on one single server.

If the answer is "yes" then you might want to try `chkdsk [hard drive letter] /f` on the server you have problem with. Since it is a server make sure you have a good backup copy of the data of the volume you "chekdsk" on although `chkdsk /f` is safe - it checks and fixs the inconsistencies on disk for you.

This answer is based on this article: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070519001528AApeRx6